# adb return 'Terminated: 15' on MACOS

Tags: android, android-studio, adb, macos-catalina

While I use “adb start-server” on my laptop，it fails and returns

> Terminated: 15

is there anyone else has met this before?
port 5037 is not occupied.

Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.41
Version 34.0.5-10900879
macos catalina v10.15.5

Thanks for help.

I tried to solve it by rebooting/ killing adb / updating the SDK version but none worked.